# Increasing effect of a (control-) variable in regression by multiplying with a constant

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am working with a large survey data set and want to control for age. However, the actual coefficient/effect of age on my dependent variable is rather small and I would like to enhance it to make it more visible (e.g. age*100). Such that my regression equation looks something like this:

`lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + age*100, data= df)`

Is there a way to make this work or do I need to modify my data (i.e., multiply all possible age values by 100)?

Comment: What do you want to do with the results/how do you want to do it?   (i.e., are you drawing coefficient plots? Creating coefficient tables? What is the intended presentation/endpoint of your analysis?)

Comment: the easiest way to magnify your coefficient would be to model age in (e.g.) centuries rather than years, which you can do by replacing `age` in the original model with `I(age/100)`

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker! I want to create a regression table with all my coefficients in it and to better understand the impact of age, make it more visible (as the effect is rather small). Your suggestion is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to magnify your coefficient would be to model age in (e.g.) centuries rather than years, which you can do by replacing age in the original model with `I(age/100)`.

Or you could post-process your regression table, multiplying the coefficients and standard errors by 100.